# how to load a UIView using a nib file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I am new to objective C so I am bit confused on how to load another UIView. here is the code I have written to goto another UIView :

```
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NotificationsView" owner:self options:nil];
```

and in the header of this file I have included notifications.h and `@class Notifications` and in the .m file I have also included notifications.h

now in the notifications.h I have made an IBOutlet for the UIView and have linked the UIView to it

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *NotificationsView;`

I have also `@synthesize NotificationsView;` in the .m file.

with all those things done, I still get an error when I try to load the nib using the code I shared at the top of this post, can someone tell me what it is that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you made all the connections to files owner in IB?

Also did you use 'viewDidLoad' to create the entire view?

Also check out this URL:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6206-how-create-uiview-uiviewcontroller-programatically-without-using-nib.html

Comment: hey, thanks that link was useful but I prefer to use NIB for now... what do you mean by creating the entire view?? lets say the code I have above is the code you get if you create the tab bar template in xcode, now I created an extra empty UIViewController file and did the things I mentioned above... now is what I have done correct in theory?? or its completely wrong?